# Reinstallation of Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, installation, localhost

I have installed the Magento which is provided in script section in **cpanel**. I want to uninstall it and want to transfer my localhost website to the live server.

Please help me to solve:-

1. How to remove the existing installed Magento.
2. Reinstall magento manually (transfering localhost site to live server step by step).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- Simply log in to **cPanel** and go to File Manager.
- Open `app/etc/local.xml` and note down **database name**, **username**, **password**, and **host**.
- Go to **PHPMyAdmin** and drop all tables under database, which was being used by Magento.
- Under `public_html` folder, delete all contents.
- Now upload your localhost files to the public_html folder.
- Import database into database using **PHPMyAdmin**.
- Change **unsecure base url** and **secure base url** in `core_config_data` table.
- Change database details under `app/etc/local.xml` file.
- Remove `/var/cache` and `/var/session` folders.
- Now refresh the browser.

**Update:** How to change unsecure base URL and secure base URL

- Open **`core_config_data`** table.
- Find path like **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and change value for the row.
- Similarly, find path like **`web/secure/base_url`** and change value for the row.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: i didn't get how to do unsecure base url point

Comment: Please check my updated answer.